# How to load libraries for gnuplot?

Tags: image, gnuplot, libraries, libpng, dyld

I installed gnuplot on macos via:

```
$ make install,
```

whenever I run

```
$ gnuplot,
```

I get the following error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libpng15.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gnuplot
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I have absolutely no idea whats going on. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Xquartz to the latest version solved it. Still have no idea what was going on

Comment: Most likely someone updated libpng from 1.5.x to 1.6.x and Xquartz was still looking for the old one.